# nginx: [emerg] "location" (/"server") directive is not allowed here

Tags: nginx, configuration, wordpress, subdomain

I've tried to create 2 separate NGINX conf files for two domains. Each domain has a test. sub domain and www shall be permanently redirected to now-www for canonical reasons. What is the proper way of doing this? I also get an error in below code.

```
sudo nginx -T 
nginx: [emerg] "location" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example.com:33
```

Here's my conf file for example.com, the second file for example2 is almost identical.

```
server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;
root /var/www/example.com/html;
index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
server_name example.com 123.456.7.8;

#(For WordPress permalinks)
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}

# Redirect all traffic to www to non-www for SEO canonical reasons
server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;
server_name www.example.com;
location / {
return 301 https://www.example.com/$request_uri;
}
}
# Direct all traffic to the subdomain to a separate folder
server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;
root /var/www/test/example.com/html;
index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
server_name test.example.com;

#(For WordPress permalinks)
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}

# include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
location ~ \.php$ {
include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
}
location = /favicon.ico { log_not_found off; access_log off;
}
location = /robots.txt { log_not_found off; access_log off; allow all;
}
location ~* \.(css|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|png)$
{
expires max;

#To enable leverage browser caching log_not_found off;
}
```

Comment: Your braces do not match which is why a `server` directive appears in the wrong block. Try indenting your code which will make it easier to read for you and everyone else. Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the entire configuration across all included files.

Comment: @RichardSmith I changed slightly now, but I still can't see which braces are not matching

Comment: As the error message states, the `server` directive on line 22 is **inside** the preceding `server` block. The block begins on line 13, a location block begins and ends on lines 17 and 19, but there is no closing brace for line 13 before line 22 is encountered.

Comment: @RichardSmith Ah, I added a closing brace on line 19 now, but then I got nginx: [emerg] "location" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example.com:33

Comment: ...which was already pointed out in my answer about an hour earlier. ‍♂️

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### You have syntax errors in your configuration

...which should be clear with both the error messages you got.

If you had used indentation in your configuration, the problem would have become obvious & easy to spot:

- The `server{}` section starding on line 13 doesn't have an ending `}`.
- Also if you simply added the `}` on line 20, the `location{}` sections on lines 33-48 would become orphan.

---

### Original configuraton with indentation

You got this error message, pointing out the problem on line 22.

```
nginx: [emerg] "server" directive is not allowed here in 
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example.com:22
```

This is not a solution, but only to demonstrate how the current configuration is interpret:

```
01: server {
02:     listen 80;
03:     listen [::]:80;
04:     root /var/www/example.com/html;
05:     index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
06:     server_name example.com 123.456.7.8;
07:
08:     #(For WordPress permalinks)
09:     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
10: }
11: 
12: # Redirect all traffic to www to non-www for SEO canonical reasons
13: server {
14:     listen 80;
15:     listen [::]:80;
16:     server_name www.example.com;
17:     location / {
18:         return 301 https://www.example.com/$request_uri;
19:     }
20: 
21:     # Direct all traffic to the subdomain to a separate folder
22:     server {
23:         listen 80;
24:         listen [::]:80;
25:         root /var/www/test/example.com/html;
26:         index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
27:         server_name test.example.com;
28: 
29:         #(For WordPress permalinks)
30:         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
31:     }
32: 
33:     # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
34:     location ~ \.php$ {
35:         include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
36:         fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
37:     }
38:     location = /favicon.ico { 
39:         log_not_found off; access_log off;
40:     }
41:     location = /robots.txt { 
42:         log_not_found off; access_log off; allow all;
43:     }
44:     location ~* \.(css|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|png)$ {
45:         expires max;
46: 
47:         #To enable leverage browser caching log_not_found off;
48:     }
```

---

### Your first attempt to fix this

...by adding a `}` (line 20) didn't help, because it didn't take my second advice into account!

```
nginx: [emerg] "location" directive is not allowed here in 
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example.com:33
```

Now, you still have the orphaned `location{}` directives, here on lines 34-47:

```
13: server {
14:     listen 80;
15:     listen [::]:80;
16:     server_name www.example.com;
17:     location / {
18:         return 301 https://www.example.com/$request_uri;
19:     }
20: }
21: # Direct all traffic to the subdomain to a separate folder
22: server {
23:     listen 80;
24:     listen [::]:80;
25:     root /var/www/test/example.com/html;
26:     index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
27:     server_name test.example.com;
28: 
29:     #(For WordPress permalinks)
30:     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
31: }
32: 
33: # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
34: location ~ \.php$ {
35:     include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
36:     fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
37: }
38: location = /favicon.ico { 
39:     log_not_found off; access_log off;
40: }
41: location = /robots.txt { 
42:     log_not_found off; access_log off; allow all;
43: }
44: location ~* \.(css|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|png)$ {
45:     expires max;
46:     #To enable leverage browser caching log_not_found off;
47: }
```

The solution is to put these `location{}` sections **inside** one of the `server{}` sections. No-one here can tell which one is the correct for them, because you don't explain that in your question: they are completely unrelated to your question about handling two domains in separate files.

---

### Finally, a clear template configuration

This configuration example tries to address your question as it is in the title. This is for the `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example.com` and the other could be `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example.net`, if you replaced all the `example.com` with `example.net`.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com test.example.com; 

    # HTTP to HTTPS redirections for all the subdomains
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.example.com;
    # ssl_* directives here

    # www to non-www for SEO canonical reasons
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;
    # ssl_* directives here

    root /var/www/example.com/html;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name test.example.com;
    # ssl_* directives here

    root /var/www/example.com/test;
}
```

Just add here the `location{}` sections as required. I also removed the additional `listen` directives for IPv6, the `index` directives etc. as they may have blinded you. Once you remove all the noise, the solution is pretty straightforward, isn't it. Then, you get to fine-tune the rest.

Comment: My intention is to create 2 separate NGINX conf files for two domains. Each domain has a test. sub domain and www shall be permanently redirected to now-www. So I thought this was the way to achieve that.

Comment: That wasn't your problem.

Comment: So do you have any solution?

Comment: First, put the directives in the correct, hierarchical order. The error messages are kind enough to even point to the row causing the error. After the configuration has a correct syntax you might face unexpected behavior, worth another question. From the current copy-pasta mix no-one can tell your intentions.

Answer (score 0):

So with my locations added inside the server blocks I guess it shall finally look like below, (without SLL for now as I will add that later with Certbot and Certbot will change my code automatically anyway).

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com;

    # www to non-www for SEO canonical reasons
    return 301 http://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    root /var/www/example.com/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    # PHP
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    }
    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off; access_log off;
    }
    location = /robots.txt {
        log_not_found off; access_log off; allow all;
    }
    location ~* \.(css|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|png)$ {
        expires max;
    }

    # (For WordPress permalinks)
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name test.example.com;

    root /var/www/example.com/test;
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    # PHP
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    }
    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off; access_log off;
    }
    location = /robots.txt {
        log_not_found off; access_log off; allow all;
    }
    location ~* \.(css|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|png)$ {
        expires max;
    }

    # (For WordPress permalinks)
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks rather good now (just fixed the intendation and removed those `# ssl_*` comments). Even with Certbot it would be better to keep full control over the configuration rather than let Certbot modify it freely.