# How to create 2 NGINX config files w sub domain in separate root folder + 2nd domain in separate root

Tags: nginx, configuration

I have two domains `example.com` and `example.net`.

- Both shall also have test sub domain like `test.example.com` pointing to different roots like root `/var/www/example.com/html` and root `/var/www/test-example.com/html`.
- The `www.example.com` & `www.example.net` shall be permanently redirected to `example.com` & `example.net`.

How shall my NGINX config files look like in this case?

Preferable 2 files `/etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com` and `/etc/nginx/sites-available/example.net` (2nd pointing to root `/var/www/example.net/html`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This is an answer modified from my [original answer](https://serverfault.com/a/1023122/274176) to your first question.*

The following configuration example is for the `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example.com` and the other could be `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example.net`, if you replaced all the `example.com` with `example.net`.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com test.example.com; 

    # HTTP to HTTPS redirections for all the subdomains
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.example.com;
    # ssl_* directives here

    # www to non-www for SEO canonical reasons
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;
    # ssl_* directives here

    root /var/www/example.com/html;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name test.example.com;
    # ssl_* directives here

    root /var/www/example.com/test;
}
```

1. The first `server{}` block upgrades plain HTTP connections to HTTPS.
2. The second `server{}` block redirects www to non-www.
3. The third `server{}` block serves files from `/var/www/example.com/html`.
4. Separate `server{}` block for `test.example.com` with a different root.